# Google Maps Javascript API not returning street_number, route

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

This issue began two days ago, and I'm seeing the same thing with the geocoding API. When I sent an address to the API through google.maps.Geocoder(); it seems to ignore the street.

The returned results are lacking the street_address and the route; the Lat/Long returned is the center of the city/town, thus not giving the correct location.

I'm seeing the same behavior in the geocoding service example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Are others experiencing this? Is it a system-wide issue?

Comment: That page works for me (returns formatted address: "532 Beacon Street, Boston, MA 02215, USA", when I enter that address; address_components[1] is "Beacon Street", with type "route").  Do you have an example address that _doesn't_ work?

Comment: I think I see what you are describing (no street_address type), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vx4x5ds/1/), but your title says "street_number, route", I do see both of those (at least in the one sample).

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into this so quickly. Very odd; it seems to have resolved itself. I previously tried several DC addresses and Illinois addresses that put me in the center of town, but now they are correct. I'll continue to monitor it.

Comment: Still having issues with this as of this being written. Extremely frustrating and seemingly without any way to control for it... if I feed "430, Triq Fleur-de-Lys" to the API, It discards the street number and send me several hundred metres in the wrong direction. If I insert the exact same address to the main Maps interface, it finds the street correctly. Argh.

Comment: may be you are entering a wrong (or non-existing) street number check your inputs - at least this was my issue. Updated @geocodezip's jsfiddle with formatted_address - http://jsfiddle.net/4vx4x5ds/4/